# How to show menu item in android application on click

Tags: android

I have to make a list menu item in android that contains three menu items in a list view i want to show some content on click of each menu.Here is a screen of which i have done so far..
[image]

This is the menu i have created .i want that i will click on Menu1 and the Menu1 will show in a page..i am posting my code..

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] menus={"Menu1","Menu2","Menu3"};

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v,int position,long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);

    String name=menus[position];

    try{
        Class main=Class.forName("com.betacoading.createlistmenu.app"+name);
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,main);
        startActivity(intent);

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,menus));
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }






@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }

   } 




public class Menu_1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_1);

    Button back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}

}


public class Menu_2 extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_2);

    Button back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    }

   }




public class Menu_3 extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_3);

    Button back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}

}


AndroidManifest.xml

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.betacoading.createlistmenu.app" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.betacoading.createlistmenu.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu_1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu_2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu_3"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

   </manifest>



Menu_1.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Menu 1"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    />




</LinearLayout>


Menu2.xml



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Menu 2"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    />




 </LinearLayout>


menu3.xml


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Menu 3"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    />
```

This is my code i have tried so far..please help me to make it dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Try this link

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/sliding-layer/

This will help you to make sliding menu from bottom, left, right, and top with lots of animation.

You can put anything inside it and easily work on it in you java class.

Hope it will help.

Comment: ok i am trying one question can it be edited with eclipse??i am new to android....

Comment: Yes it is an open source library.. you can easily implement it in your project by giving reference to the library.